# How to implement android XML for the attached image (layout)?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I need to implement my android layout as the image below:

[image]

**A** - **Should hold the components in the following manner**
[image]

**B** - **Should take up 75% of the screen space and should have a vertical scroll bar**

My question is, how would my Android XML look like? Guys thanks in advance.

My XML is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <NumberPicker
            android1:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignTop="@+id/numberPicker1"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker1" />

        <NumberPicker
            android1:id="@+id/numberPicker3"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignTop="@+id/numberPicker2"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker2" />

        <NumberPicker
            android1:id="@+id/numberPicker4"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignBottom="@+id/numberPicker3"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker3" />

        <NumberPicker
            android1:id="@+id/numberPicker5"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignTop="@+id/numberPicker4"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker4" />

        <NumberPicker
            android1:id="@+id/numberPicker6"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignBottom="@+id/numberPicker5"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker5" />

        <NumberPicker
            android1:id="@+id/numberPicker7"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignBottom="@+id/numberPicker6"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker6" />

        <NumberPicker
            android1:id="@+id/numberPicker8"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignTop="@+id/numberPicker7"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker7" />

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/textView1"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignLeft="@+id/numberPicker1"
            android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android1:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android1:text="Start Mileage"
            android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android1:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android1:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
            android1:src="@drawable/line" />

        <Button
            android1:id="@+id/button1"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android1:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
            android1:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android1:text="Request Bundle" />

        <EditText
            android1:id="@+id/editText2"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
            android1:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android1:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
            android1:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/textView4"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android1:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android1:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android1:text="Driver Name"
            android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android1:id="@+id/editText3"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
            android1:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
            android1:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
            android1:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/textView5"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
            android1:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
            android1:layout_marginTop="31dp"
            android1:text="Number of passengers"
            android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android1:id="@+id/editText4"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
            android1:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
            android1:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
            android1:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/textView3"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android1:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android1:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android1:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            android1:text="Vehicle Number"
            android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/textView2"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
            android1:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android1:text="Date"
            android1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android1:id="@+id/editText1"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText4"
            android1:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
            android1:ems="10" >


            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <NumberPicker
            android1:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android1:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android1:layout_marginLeft="242dp"
            android1:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: try combine ScrollView + RelativeLayout

Comment: I just added the XML. But its completely non what i wanted.. A vertical separater image separates the layout instead of a layout doing that separation job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I think you should read your requirements once more yourself. You already mentioned A and B, so obviously you have to use *two* containers (assuming you are sure, that Fragments aren't a better choice). Why do you use only one?

And only wrap the second container with a scrollview. If you put the ScrollView at the outer most level *everything* scrolls!

Use an outer LinearView and give the inner containers some weights (the left one `android:layout_weight="1"` and the right one `android:layout_weight="3"`). Weights use any remaining space and distribute it according to their percentage of the toal weight. So in this case you have 25% and 75%.

You should really read about those layouts. See the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) about it or have a look at the blog [Styling Android](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/297). If you cannot understand what the Eclipse layout editor generates, you won't get desired results with it.